# Things I would need to learn

Tags: html, css

Hello everyone and thanks in advance for helping me out. I just graduated from a video game conception school and I want to get into UX for video game or mobile app. The issue is: I don't know where to start. I am already very comfortable with Adobe products but I don't know anything about coding. So I'm not sure about the next step to take.

Should I learn HTML & CSS?
Should I learn Java or any programming language?
Do you recommend this course? [Udemy mobile app design](https://www.udemy.com/mobile-app-design-from-scratch/?affcode=E0IZcVxaT34ARh9j&couponCode=UX%20Mastery%20review%20$49)

My goal is to develop a skill in UX that is strong enough so I can partner up with a programmer and create app or games.

Thanks.

Comment: What did you learn in video game conception school? UX is a broad term that encompasses a whole world of skills from graphic design, to psychology, to data analysis, to writing code, to user research, etc, etc. As such, I'd say learn what you are interested in.

Answer (score 2):

To get you up to speed fast, spend your next ten hours reading "[Don't make me think"](http://www.sensible.com/dmmt.html) by Steve Krug. When your done, tweet me and I'll be more than happy to guide you through the available literature.

[image]

Comment: @LindaBrammer Thanks! The more who know UX, the better!

Comment: And there is a useful question on here on Recommended UX Books for follow on reading...